# Python BeautifulSoup - How to extract this text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, extract, data-extraction

**Current Python script:**

```
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<div class="info">
    <h1>Company Title</h1>
    <p class="type">Company type</p>
    <p class="address"><strong>ZIP, City</strong></p>
    <p class="address"><strong>Street 123</strong></p>
    <p style="margin-top:10px;"> Phone: <strong>(111) 123-456-78</strong><br />
        Fax: <strong>(222) 321-654-87</strong><br />
        Phone: <strong>(333) 87-654-321</strong><br />
        Fax: <strong>(444) 000-1111-2222</strong><br />
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top:10px;"> E-mail: <a href="mailto:mail@domain.com">mail@domain.com</a><br />
    E-mail: <a href="mailto:mail2@domain.com">mail2@domain.com</a><br />
    </p>
    <p> Web: <a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank">www.domain.com</a><br />
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top:10px;"> ID: <strong>123456789</strong><br />
        VAT: <strong>987654321</strong> </p>
    <p class="del" style="margin-top:10px;">Some info:</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#category">&raquo; Category</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
'''

html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

p = html.find_all('p', attrs={'class': None})

for pp in p:
    print(pp.contents)
```

**It returns the following:**

```
[' Phone: ', <strong>123-456-78</strong>, <br/>, '\n\t\tFax: ', <strong>321-654-87</strong>, <br/>, '\n\t\tPhone: ', <strong>87-654-321</strong>, <br/>, '\n\t\tFax: ', <strong>000-1111-2222</strong>, <br/>, '\n']
[' E-mail: ', <a href="mailto:mail@domain.com">mail@domain.com</a>, <br/>, '\n\tE-mail: ', <a href="mailto:mail2@domain.com">mail2@domain.com</a>, <br/>, '\n']
[' Web: ', <a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank">www.domain.com</a>, <br/>, '\n']
[' ID: ', <strong>123456789</strong>, <br/>, '\n\t\tVAT: ', <strong>987654321</strong>, ' ']
```

**Problem:**
I dont know how to extract text for phone, fax and email, id, vat and create array from them, something like:

```
phones = [123-456-78, 87-654-321]
faxes = [321-654-87, 000-1111-2222]
emails = [mail@domain.com, mail2@domain.com]
id = [123456789]
vat = [987654321]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group the data using a defaultdict after splitting:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

p = html.find_all('p', attrs={'class': None})
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for pp in p:
    spl = iter(pp.text.split(None,1))
    for ele in spl:
        d[ele.rstrip(":")].append(next(spl).rstrip())

print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Phone': ['123-456-78', '87-654-321'],
'Fax': ['321-654-87', '000-1111-2222'], 'E-mail': ['mail@domain.com',
'mail2@domain.com'], 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Web': ['www.domain.com'], 
'ID': ['123456789']})
```

Splitting the text gives you lists of data gives you:

```
['Phone:', '123-456-78', 'Fax:', '321-654-87', 'Phone:', '87-654-321', 'Fax:', '000-1111-2222']
['E-mail:', 'mail@domain.com', 'E-mail:', 'mail2@domain.com']
['Web:', 'www.domain.com']
['ID:', '123456789', 'VAT:', '987654321']
```

So we use every two elements as key/value pairs. appending for repeated keys.

For your edit to catch  spaces in the fax and phone numbers just split into lines with splitlines and split once on whitespace:
from collections import defaultdict

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for pp in p:
    spl = pp.text.splitlines()
    for ele in spl:
        k, v = ele.strip().split(None, 1)
        d[k.rstrip(":")].append(v.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Fax': ['(222) 321-654-87', '(444) 000-1111-2222'],
 'Web': ['www.domain.com'], 'ID': ['123456789'], 'E-mail': ['mail@domain.com', 'mail2@domain.com'],
 'VAT': ['987654321'], 'Phone': ['(111) 123-456-78', '(333) 87-654-321']})
```

Comment: Sorry, im getting error, when phone number is like `(111) 222-333-4444`

Comment: Thanks for the update! I get now another problem. Phone is containing: `'Phone': ['(111) 123-456-78\n\t\tFax: (222) 321-654-87\n\t\tPhone: (333) 87-654-321\n\t\tFax: (444) 000-1111-2222']` I mean its not split to `Phone` and `Fax`

Comment: I solved it using:
`for pp in p:
    spl = iter(pp.text.splitlines())
    for ele in spl:
        for spl2 in ele.splitlines():
            spl3 = iter(spl2.split(None, 1))
            print(spl3)
            for ele2 in spl3:
                d[ele2.rstrip(":")].append(next(spl3).rstrip())`

its not elegant, but it works :)

Comment: @RhymeGuy,  the edit should do what  you need in a bit less code ;)